# Android; I only have 2 contacts, yet I can obtain 5 from a query, why?

Tags: android, cursor, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

I have setup 2 test contacts in my emulator.

I'm running the following query, it should pick them both out, populate my domain object, and add to a list. The output at the bottom should therefore be 2, but it is 5, why is this? (cursor.getCount() is 5 instead of 2)

I have stepped through each iteration of the while loop and it is retreving the same contact multiple times, but with different values for `POSTCODE`, such as the phone number

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        List<MeCercanaContact> contacts = new ArrayList<MeCercanaContact>();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                MyContact myContact = new MyContact();
                String givenName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String postcode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                myContact.setFirstName(givenName);
                myContact.setLastName(postcode);
                contacts.add(myContact);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(contacts.size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying ContactsContract.Data, which is a generic container that holds a list of various contact details, such as phone numbers, postal codes etc.. You must filter the results for the rows whose ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE column equals StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE:

So change the query to:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
     null, null, ContacsContract.Data.MIMETYPE +  "='" + 
ContactsContract.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
```

See [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)

Answer (score 2):

After API 21 We Write this Query for remove contact duplicacy.

```
String select = ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 AND " + 
ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                + " = " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + " 
AND "+ ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + 
ContactsContract.Data.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID;

Cursor cursor = mContent.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, select, 
 null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

a contact that is registered to multiple groups will show up multiple times
if you query the  `Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`

Add this to your SELECTION:

```
 + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + " = 1 " ;  //show only contacts in group 1
```