# Android Contacts Content Provider returns multiple copies of same contact, no duplicate contacts in contacts

Tags: android, contacts

```
public static String getContactName(Context context, String id, String address){

        if(id==null){
            if(address==null){
                return null;
            }else{
                return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(address);
            }
        }

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);

        if(cursor!=null){
            try{
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getColumnCount();++i){
                            String columnName = cursor.getColumnName(i);
                            String columnText = cursor.getString(i);
                            Log.d(columnName, columnText==null ? "null":columnText);
                        }
                        Log.d("endline","***************************");
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());


                }else{
                    Log.d("cursor", "not greater than 0");
                }
            }finally{
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        if(address != null){
            return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(address);
        }

        return "just testing shit";
    }
```

So my problem is that when I return all my contacts I get multiple copies of each contact and I am not sure why, or what to do about this. I looked in my contacts both online here: https://www.google.com/contacts/#contacts

As well as deleted all contacts from my phone and resynced to google contacts to make sure there were no duplicates. I cannot understand whats happening, although Im probably just being stupid somehow.

Here is what the output looks like (truncated to a few contacts)

First one:

```
sort_key: James LaChance
photo_uri: null
status_label: null
status_ts: null
status_res_package: null
name_verified: 0
display_name: James LaChance
last_time_used: null
mimetype: vnd.android.cursor.item/photo
phonebook_label_alt: L
data6: null
version: 3
photo_id: null
data3: null
custom_ringtone: null
times_contacted: 0
account_type_and_data_set: com.google
dirty: 0
data7: null
data15: null
raw_contact_is_user_profile: 0
data_set: null
phonebook_label: J
data10: null
res_package: null
account_type: com.google
data11: null
display_name_alt: LaChance, James
lookup: 3448i1629e6890832873d
phonetic_name: null
last_time_contacted: 0
contact_last_updated_timestamp: 1403954657613
data13: null
in_visible_group: 1
chat_capability: null
data9: null
data_sync1: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/jmsmaupin1%40gmail.com/1629e6890832873d  
sort_key_alt: LaChance, James
contact_presence: null
data_version: 0
phonetic_name_style: 0
name_raw_contact_id: 1
raw_contact_id: 1
send_to_voicemail: 0
data4: null
data12: null
contact_status: null
contact_status_label: null
pinned: 2147483647
status_icon: null
status: null
data1: null
phonebook_bucket: 10
data_sync2: null
contact_status_res_package: null
in_default_directory: 1
_id: 1
is_super_primary: 0
data5: null
contact_id: 8
data8: null
is_primary: 0
data_sync4: 0
has_phone_number: 1
display_name_source: 40
photo_file_id: null
data_sync3: null
data14: null
contact_status_ts: null
phonebook_bucket_alt: 12
mode: null
data2: null
group_sourceid: null
starred: 0
photo_thumb_uri: null
times_used: null
contact_status_icon: null
contact_chat_capability: null
sourceid: 1629e6890832873d
```

Second one:

```
sort_key: James LaChance
photo_uri: null
status_label: null
status_ts: null
status_res_package: null
name_verified: 0
display_name: James LaChance
last_time_used: null
mimetype: vnd.android.cursor.item/name
phonebook_label_alt: L
data6: null
version: 3
photo_id: null
data3: LaChance
custom_ringtone: null
times_contacted: 0
account_type_and_data_set: com.google
dirty: 0
data7: null
data15: null
raw_contact_is_user_profile: 0
data_set: null
phonebook_label: J
data10: 1
res_package: null
account_type: com.google
data11: 0
display_name_alt: LaChance, James
lookup: 3448i1629e6890832873d
phonetic_name: null
last_time_contacted: 0
contact_last_updated_timestamp: 1403954657613
data13: null
in_visible_group: 1
chat_capability: null
data9: null
data_sync1: null
sort_key_alt: LaChance, James
contact_presence: null
data_version: 0
phonetic_name_style: 0
name_raw_contact_id: 1
raw_contact_id: 1
send_to_voicemail: 0
data4: null
data12: null
contact_status: null
contact_status_label: null
pinned: 2147483647
status_icon: null
status: null
data1: James LaChance
phonebook_bucket: 10
data_sync2: null
contact_status_res_package: null
in_default_directory: 1
_id: 2
is_super_primary: 0
data5: null
contact_id: 8
data8: null
is_primary: 0
data_sync4: 10
has_phone_number: 1
display_name_source: 40
photo_file_id: null
data_sync3: null
data14: null
contact_status_ts: null
phonebook_bucket_alt: 12
mode: null
data2: James
group_sourceid: null
starred: 0
photo_thumb_uri: null
times_used: null
contact_status_icon: null
contact_chat_capability: null
sourceid: 1629e6890832873d
```

Im an idiot. I found the answer to my question almost immediately after I asked this question.

refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591323/2408279

Essentially there is a reference for each contact type I.E. email, phone etc. (if im not mistaken)

Comment: i don't know the answer but use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor in the future

Comment: I did not know that was a thing... I feel stupid now haha.

Comment: why stupid? Errare humanum est

Comment: the same problem. but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should query the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`, `CONTENT_URI` table instead, let me know if it helped.

And as pskink said, use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` to log the cursor.. simpler