# How to get non duplicated phone numbers from android contacts content provider

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to get all contacts which have mobile numbers.
I am able to fetch the contacts.But the problem is it gives me duplicate contacts.same phone number comes two times.

I used the following code to get contacts.

```
public static List<RawContact>  getAllContacts(Context context,Account account){
        Log.d(TAG, "*** Looking for local contacts with mobile number!!");
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;
        int numberOfContacts = 0;
        List<RawContact> newContacts = new ArrayList<RawContact>();
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        List<RawContact> localNewContacts = new ArrayList<RawContact>();
        final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if(cursor.getCount()>0){
            numberOfContacts = 0;
            Log.d(TAG, "*** Looking for local contacts "+cursor.getCount());
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                final long rawContactId = cursor.getLong(DirtyQuery.COLUMN_RAW_CONTACT_ID);
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    //This is to read multiple phone numbers associated with the same contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'google' "+" AND "+ Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        Log.d(TAG,"Phone number is: "+phoneNumber);
                        RawContact rawContact = getRawContact(context, rawContactId);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + rawContact.getBestName());
                        localNewContacts.add(rawContact);
                    }phoneCursor.close();
            }
            numberOfContacts++;
            Log.d(TAG, "numberOfContacts updated: "+numberOfContacts);
        }

    }
        return localNewContacts;
    }
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: tis also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069014/android-get-phone-contacts-and-remove-duplicates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185338/android-duplicate-contact-data-while-retrieving-contacts-using-contactscontrac

Comment: You can try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185338/android-duplicate-contact-data-while-retrieving-contacts-using-contactscontrac

Answer (score 1):

You're getting duplicate contacts because you're actually reading `RawContacts`, not contacts. Multiple `RawContact`s can and will contain info about a single person represented by a single `Contact`.

You need a single query over the `Phones` table, and organize the data using a HashMap from `CONTACT_ID` to Contact info, so you won't get duplicates.

The Contacts DB is organized in three main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

You're trying to make a query on the `Contacts` table, with projection of fields from the `Data` table, you can't do that.

You can use something like the following code, just convert the `HashMap` to work with your `ContactModel` object:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3 };
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data (e.g. "phone")
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234
    int type = cur.getInt(4); // a numeric value representing type: e.g. home / office / personal
    String label = cur.getString(5); // a custom label in case type is "TYPE_CUSTOM"

    String labelStr = Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + kind + " - " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + " = " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");
}
```

Comment: got 411, At Saravanan, kind - +44 7438 306573 (Mobile)
04-18 12:11:19.142 9560-9939/com.example.android.samplesync D/ContactManager: Result executed!!
04-18 12:11:19.142 9560-9939/com.example.android.samplesync D/ContactManager: got 411, At Saravanan, kind - +447438306573 (Mobile)
04-18 12:11:19.142 9560-9939/com.example.android.samplesync D/ContactManager: Result executed!!

Comment: im getting results like this

Comment: yes, you can format those phones into e164 and compare them to avoid adding similar phones with different format.

Comment: see this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumberToE164(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: im trying to sync contacts to my server but only need to show contacts that are using our service in contacts should i give source id value to all contacts or only ones using our service

Comment: how to sync contacts that only use my service??

Comment: that's not a question i can answer, that's up to your service requirements and design

Answer (score 0):

**Here is quick solution i came up with**

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                              null,
                                              null,
                                              null,
                                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

        contactArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String tempId = "";

        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));

                if(!tempId.equals(contact_id)){
                    String contact_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contact_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String result = contact_id+"\n"+contact_name+"\n"+contact_number;
                    contactArray.add(result);
                }

                tempId = contact_id;

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            cursor.close();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.