# Contact number fetched shows duplicate number(Whatsapp and duo numbers)

Tags: android

I am creating an application which will display phone numbers of a contact in alert dialog box as list.My problem is it will show duplicate numbers where the contact does not have duplicate number in phones contact application.(My asssumption is it is fetching from whatsapp number, duo number etc.)

This is my contact fetching code inside onActivityResult.

```
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (reqCode) {
                    case REQUEST_CODE:
                        final TextView phoneInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        String phoneNumber = "";
                        List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                        int phoneIdx = 0;
                        try {
                            Uri result = data.getData();
                            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
                            phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                                    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                                    allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                                    cursor.moveToNext();
                                }
                            } else {
                                //no results actions
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //error actions
                        } finally {
                            if (cursor != null) {
                                cursor.close();
                            }

                            final CharSequence[] items = allNumbers.toArray(new String[allNumbers.size()]);
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Choose a number");
                            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                    String selectedNumber = items[item].toString();
                                    selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");
                                    phoneInput.setText(selectedNumber);
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            if(allNumbers.size() > 1) {
                                alert.show();
                            } else {
                                String selectedNumber = phoneNumber.toString();
                                selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");
                                phoneInput.setText(selectedNumber);
                            }

                            if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {
                                //no numbers found actions
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                //activity result error actions
            }
```

Comment: use hashmap for numbers and get the filtered array.

Comment: @AwaisTariq bro can you help me with some sample?

Comment: Your question is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851846/how-to-get-non-duplicated-phone-numbers-from-android-contacts-content-provider

Comment: while inserting into list, do use hashmap.put(number,name) so whenever same number comes it will not add into the map.

Comment: @AwaisTariq let me check bro

Comment: @AwaisTariq bro i cant implement what you say...please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one, hope this helps

```
Map<String, String> filteredList = new HashMap<>();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (reqCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE:
                    final TextView phoneInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    String phoneNumber = "";
                    List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                    int phoneIdx = 0;
                    try {
                        Uri result = data.getData();
                        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
                        phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                                allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                                filteredList.put(phoneNumber,"name");
                                cursor.moveToNext();
                            }
                        } else {
                            //no results actions
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //error actions
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }

                        final CharSequence[] items = allNumbers.toArray(new String[allNumbers.size()]);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Choose a number");
                        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                String selectedNumber = items[item].toString();
                                selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");
                                phoneInput.setText(selectedNumber);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        if(allNumbers.size() > 1) {
                            alert.show();
                        } else {
                            String selectedNumber = phoneNumber.toString();
                            selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");
                            phoneInput.setText(selectedNumber);
                        }

                        if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) {
                            //no numbers found actions
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            //activity result error actions
        }
```

Comment: Impossible. Use filteredList where u need it

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashMap to store the contact list. HashMap doesn't contains duplicate key, so no duplicate value will store in it.